# Parsing script portion of a .vue file to infer types and generate documentation

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have developed a VSCode extension to generate JSDoc for TypeScript files.
I have been asked to add support for `.vue` files and I'd like to do so, however it's harder than just activating my extension for `.vue` files too.

For reference, [this](https://github.com/Nyphet/jsdoc-generator) is my repository and [this](https://github.com/Nyphet/jsdoc-generator/issues/6) is the relevant issue.

I tried to add vue as an activation event:

```
"activationEvents": [
  "onLanguage:typescript",
  "onLanguage:typescriptreact",
  "onLanguage:javascript",
  "onLanguage:javascriptreact",
  "onLanguage:vue"
]
```

And then adding it to the languages that trigger my completion item:

```
vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider(
  [
    {
      scheme: 'file',
      language: 'typescript'
    },
    {
      scheme: 'file',
      language: 'typescriptreact'
    },
    {
      scheme: 'file',
      language: 'javascript'
    },
    {
      scheme: 'file',
      language: 'javascriptreact'
    },
    {
      scheme: 'file',
      language: 'vue'
    }
  ],
  {
    provideCompletionItems(document: TextDocument, position: Position, _: CancellationToken) {
      // Return my list of completion items.
    }
  },
  '/',
  '*'
);
```

But although this does make my completion item appear:
[image]
When I select it, nothing is added and I get the following error (yes, the path is correct):

> [error] Error: Could not find source file: 'path/to/file/filename.vue'.
> at getValidSourceFile
> at Object.getSyntacticDiagnostics
> at JsdocGenerator.retrieveTsFile
> at JsdocGenerator.generateJsdoc
> Which is thrown by my function

```
private retrieveTsFile(document: TextDocument, caret?: Position): TsFile {
  const fileText = document.getText();
  const fileName = this.getDocumentFileName(document);
  this.languageServiceHost.updateFile(fileName, fileText); // This only adds the filename to an internal object of languageServiceHost that keeps track of some stuff
  this.languageService.getSyntacticDiagnostics(fileName); // The error happens here
  const program = this.languageService.getProgram();
  return new TsFile(fileName, document.getText(), caret, program);
}
```

I believe it's due to the fact that `.vue` files can't be parsed by a TypeScript LanguageService created as follows:

```
constructor() {
  // Constructor of the class owning the retrieveTsFile method
  this.languageServiceHost = new LanguageServiceHost();
  this.languageService = createLanguageService(this.languageServiceHost, createDocumentRegistry());
}
```

But I don't know how to make up for that.
What are possible solutions?